# Integer array error while displaying data

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an attrribute `evenNum` which contains array of even numbers, I like to print the array stored in attribute to console
like this

> ["2, 6, 8, 10" , "24, 22, 20", "2, 6, 34"]

so I did this and got the error which is shown in comment below

```
 var evenNumArr:[Int] = []

let results = try context.fetch(request)

    if results.count > 0
    {
        for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]
        { 

  if let evenNumbers = result.value(forKey: "evenNum") as? [Int]
    {
        //Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to excepted argument type 'int'
        evenNumArr.append(evenNumbers)
    }
    }
    print(evenNumArr)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your output, with the quotes, implies that you have an array of strings. "2, 6, 8, 10" looks like a string to me. Do you just want to display your array like that? What is the reason for the groupings in quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want an array of arrays. You need to change how `evenNumArr` is declared:

```
var evenNumArr:[[Int]] = []

if let evenNumbers = result.value(forKey: "evenNum") as? [Int]
{
    evenNumArr.append(evenNumbers)
}

print(evenNumArr)
```

Comment: I edited question with result. After implementing your solution, I am getting values this time in array like this [2, 6, 8, 10 , 24, 22, 20, 2, 6, 34] but not in pairs like in question

Comment: There are no pairs in your question. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean 2, 6, 8, 10 are stored in one array and 24, 22, 20 are stored in other. Sorry for my language

Answer (score 0):

It tells you right in the error.  You're trying to append `evenNumbers` which you've declared as type `[Int]` in:

```
let evenNumbers = result.value(forKey: "evenNum") as? [Int]
```

To an `evenNumArr` array made up of `Int`'s

You can only append the same type as the array contains.

In Swift you can combine arrays as such:

```
let ones = [Int]()
var twos = [Int]()
twos += ones
```